# Prove that the figure is a trapezoid...

Tags: geometry

[image]

Knowing that triangle $ABC$ is an arbitrary one,  points $D$,$F$,$G$ are midpoints of respective sides of the triangle(as you see in the picture ), and $CE$ is the altitude, prove that $DG$ is congruent to $EF$ thus $DEFG$ is an isoscel trapezoid.

$MY WORK:$ I tried to work with angles but had no result from this.

I would like to receive just an understandable hint.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not at all convinced that the claim is true. You can show that $\triangle FGD \sim \triangle ABC$, but I'm not sure how that helps you. What happens if $\triangle ABC$ is obtuse, so $CE$ is outside the triangle?

Comment: I've already understood how to solve it. From triangle $DEC$ which we see is a right triangle $EF$ is the mediane, thus $EF=1/2BC$. Now, the same we have for $DG$ which is a midsegment, so it is also half the length of $BC$. So it's an isoscel trapezoid.

Comment: Indeed so, @JohnG.: you nailed it.

Comment: @DOn Antonio Thank you that you viewed my problem!

Comment: @PaulZ Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @JohnG., just one thing: in your last comment, it must be "In triangle $\;BEC\;,\;\;EF\;$ is the median to the hypotenuse and thus its length is half that of the hypotenuse"

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand, thanks. It's my mistake.